# HttpContext.Current.Session is null

Tags: session

I'm loading a page with WebPart in it, and I get `NullReferenceException` in this line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Foo"] = value;
```

because `Session` is `null`. The web.config under `inetpub` folder has

```
<pages enableSessionState="false" ... >
```

Does session bag being null is caused by this setting in `web.config`, or is the cause completely different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, If you want to use the session-state, you should enable it in the web.config of the webapplication.

To enable ASP.NET session state:

1. Enter the following PowerShell command in the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell window:
   **Enable-SPSessionStateService –DefaultProvision**
   or more advanced:
   **Enable-SPSessionStateService 
   -DatabaseName  
   [-DatabaseServer ] 
   [-DatabaseCredentials ]**
2. On each web application for which you want to use session state,
   edit the web.config file and set the enableSessionState property of
   the pages element as follows:
    **< pages enableSessionState="true"**

Comment: This solution works 100%, verified.

Comment: run Sharepoint Powershell as admin of cource

Comment: I have a SharePoint site where I use HttpContext.Current.Session["Foo"] = value; But pages enableSessionState is set to false. But it does work. What does the pages enableSessionState="true" actually do?

Answer (score 2):

To use session state in SharePoint see [Using Session State in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx), but think hard about if you really want to do it.

Comment: Why should I think hard about it? are there any drawbacks?